# sending ajax value into two pages

Tags: php, ajax

how do i send this value into two pages ?

so far i have this,

```
function DinamisCountry(combobox)
{
var kode = combobox.value;
if (!kode) return;
xmlhttp.open('get', 'template/get_provinsi-opr.php?kode='+kode, true);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if ((xmlhttp.readyState == 4) && (xmlhttp.status == 200))
    {
         document.getElementById("provinsi").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
    return false;
}
xmlhttp.send(null);
}
```

its only sending the value into get_provinsi-opr.php,
how do i send the value into the other page ? do i need to store it in a session ?
I am implemnting 3 dropdown lists but the last dropdown need the value from the first dropdown.

Comment: you will have to do another ajax request to the second location

Comment: @lagbox if i do another ajax request how about the onChange call in the markup ? i have this
onChange="DinamisCountry(this);" . can i have two function calls ??

Comment: you can make another request inside of that function

Comment: you may make a another ajax request in the function you have mentioned or make another function and call it in the onChange in this format onChange="DinamisCountry(this); xyz(this)"

Comment: @lagbox u mean something like this ?? http://pastebin.com/tDM10UYp